# How do I take a "screenshot" of an NSView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, nsimage

I need to take the contents of an `NSView` and put them in an `NSImage`, for an experimental project. Is this possible? I did some Googling, tried two methods that I found - but they didn't really work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which methods didn't work and why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[view dataWithPDFInsideRect:[view bounds]]];
```

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that, although this is the right way in general, there are some cases where it will not work, eg views like `NSOpenGLView` that have their own OpenGL rendering context. In that case you need to get the pixel data directly and create a bitmap rep from it, which is a bit less neat.

Comment: Obs: shadows and cornerRadius will be ignored

Comment: If view is layer backed (wantsLayer = YES) this solution will ignore some layer properties, like backgroundColor, cornerRadius etc. I recommend code from another answer, using cacheDisplayInRect function, it should work in all cases.

Answer (score 33):

From WWDC 2012 Session 245 (translated to Swift):

```
let viewToCapture = self.window!.contentView!
let rep = viewToCapture.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: viewToCapture.bounds)!
viewToCapture.cacheDisplay(in: viewToCapture.bounds, to: rep)

let img = NSImage(size: viewToCapture.bounds.size)
img.addRepresentation(rep)
```

Comment: swift 3
let rep = viewToCapture.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: viewToCapture.bounds)!
                viewToCapture.cacheDisplay(in: viewToCapture.bounds, to: rep)
                
                let img = NSImage(size: viewToCapture.bounds.size)
                img.addRepresentation(rep)

Comment: Note: doesn't always work correctly. I'm having issued with a label that has a rotated coordinate system.

Comment: This was the best solution for me, unlike the pdf version, this also accounts for shadows and rounded corners. Unlike the window cap version, this only captures the current view. 

Obj C code: 
`- (NSImage *)screenCap {
 NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
 [self cacheDisplayInRect:self.bounds toBitmapImageRep:bitmap];
 NSImage *result = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.bounds.size];
 [result addRepresentation:bitmap];
 return result;
}
`

Comment: I've been using this successfully in 10.14 & 10.15 (codrut's Obj C version above) but for some reason I get no image on 10.13.

Comment: I had the problem that subviews with `visible=NO`were still showing up in the PDF version. Using this version solved it. Still looking for a solution, though, which will also include an `AVPlayerView`'s current frame. Suggestions welcome :)

Comment: I'm using an NSBox with .underPageBackgroundColor as the fillColor and this doesn't capture the color properly

Answer (score 6):

```
let dataOfView = view.dataWithPDFInsideRect(view.bounds)
let imageOfView = NSImage(data: dataOfView)
```

Answer (score -1):

`NSView.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay()` (mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37702996/10601702)) doesn't render the colors correctly on some views.

`CGWindowListCreateImage()` works perfectly for me.

Here's my implementation:

```swift
extension NSView {
    @objc func takeScreenshot() -> NSImage? {
        
        let screenRect = self.rectInQuartzScreenCoordinates()
        guard let window = self.window else { 
            assert(false); return nil 
        }
        let windowID = CGWindowID(window.windowNumber)
        guard let screenshot = CGWindowListCreateImage(screenRect, .optionIncludingWindow, windowID, []) else { 
            assert(false); return nil 
        }
        
        return NSImage(cgImage: screenshot, size: self.frame.size)
    }
}
```

This code uses a method `NSView.rectInQuartzScreenCoordinates()`. To implement it you'll first have to convert the bounds of your view to screenCoordinates using `NSView` and `NSWindow` methods and then you need to flip the coordinates like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74501612/10601702).