# In Objective-C (OS X), is the "global display" coordinate space used by Quartz Display Services the same as Cocoa's "screen" coordinate space?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, coordinates, quartz-graphics

I'm attempting to create an image "loupe" for my application that can be used to inspect images at different magnification levels, and I have run into a bit of a road bump. I'm using Quartz to create a `CGImageRef` snapshot of a selected portion of the display my app's window is on. The problem is, the nomenclature used by all of the different OS X technologies has me really confused.

The function I'm using is `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(CGDirectDisplayID display, CGRect rect)`. The documentation states the `CGRect rect` parameter is the "rectangle, specified in *display space*, for the portion of the display being copied into the image." The problem is, the output I'm getting in my console isn't what I was expecting. I've tried so many different conversions, transformations, coord flips, etc., that I'm 100% confused now.

So, I guess my question boils down to this: Does screen space == device space == display space, and how does one properly convert his or her view's frame (which happens to be a custom borderless window) coordinates (bottom-left origin) to match the display's coordinates (top-left origin)?

If someone could set me straight, or point me in the right direction, I'd be forever appreciative. Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quartz uses a coordinate space where the origin (0, 0) is at the top-left of the primary display. Increasing y goes down.

Cocoa uses a coordinate space where the origin (0, 0) is the bottom-left of the primary display and increasing y goes up.

You can convert a window's frame from Cocoa to Quartz like so:

```
NSRect frame = window.frame;
frame.origin.y = NSMaxY(NSScreen.screens[0].frame) - NSMaxY(frame);
CGRect quartzRect = NSRectToCGRect(frame);
```

Note: you don't use the window's `-screen`, you always use the primary screen.

This is for a rect in window coordinates. For a rect in a view, first convert from view coordinates to window coordinates using `-[NSView convertRect:toView:]` with `nil` as the destination view signifying the window. This would do the right thing for `someView.bounds` but not for `someView.frame`, since a view's frame is in the superview's coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. I've since fixed my issue by commenting everything out (including my thousands of `NSLog()` calls), and starting from scratch. I think my biggest issue was that I had so many conversions and coordinate flips going on, one would cancel out the other. I really appreciate your breakdown though. I never thought about the bounds/frame difference. That's probably where I went wrong. My only question remaining is: does "screen space" equal "device space?" And are they synonymous with "global display space?" I'm starting to think I have a big space in between my ears. :-(

Comment: "Device space" refers to pixels. Its origin is typically specific to the device. "Local display space" uses points but its origin is at the top-left of the specific display. "Global display space" is a unified coordinate space in which all displays are situated. Its origin is at the top-left of the primary display. "Screen space" is the Cocoa coordinate space with its origin at the bottom-left of the primary display.

Comment: @KenThomases      - How do we convert a point with an inverted 'cocoa Y' to normal 'Quartz y' ? I tried ur logic but the Y coordinate is going negative................. nsRect.origin.y = NSMaxY(NSScreen.screens[0].frame) - NSMaxY(nsRect); CGRect cropRect = NSRectToCGRect(nsRect);

Comment: @kamyFC The conversion works just the same either way, so what you showed seems right. A negative Y coordinate might be correct, depending on what your `nsRect` is meant to represent. It just means a rectangle above the top of the primary screen. That might be a secondary screen or just something that's partially off the top of the screen. Is your `nsRect` in screen space (as opposed to, for example, relative to a view in a window)?

Comment: @KenThomases
Yes the Y from point comes from this code - NSPoint currentPoint = [self.view convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil]; 
so this seems to be screen space right?

Comment: @KenThomases
also after using the formulae - 
If i click near top edge of the view, i get flippedY = 510 to 515
If i click near bottom edge of the view, i get flippedY = 965 to 970

At the top edge it should be between 0 to 10.  This is strange :-|

Comment: I've seen a handful of other posts mention that the coordinate system is relative to the "main" display. Just to prevent other folks like me, this is _not_ the same as `NSScreen.main`, which is the screen that the keyboard currently has focus on.

Comment: What is the purpose of `NSRectToCGRect`? `NSRect` is just a `typealias` to `CGRect`