# Convert point to global coordinates

Tags: swift, macos, coordinates

I'm creating a `CGEvent` as such:

```
let event = CGEvent(source: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: ..., mouseButton: .left)
```

Now `mouseCursorPosition` requires Global Coordinates: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1454356-init

Now I believe Global Coordinates is that the Top Left corner is at 0, 0

Problem:

I have an `NSPoint`, which is expressed in the current view's coordinates. I need to convert that `NSPoint` into the Global Coordinates.

I saw this near duplicate: [Mac OS X: Convert between NSView coordinates and global screen coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751105/mac-os-x-convert-between-nsview-coordinates-and-global-screen-coordinates)

However, when i try that code, it seems to still be in Screen Coordinates, which means that the top left corner is:

0, ScreenHeight

That's not good, it's supposed to be in Global Coordinates.

Comment: `NSEvent.mouseLocation` ?

Comment: See [Mac OS X Cocoa, Flipping Y Coordinate in Global Screen Coordinate Space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45289010)