# How do I make a thumbnail view form custom view(NSView)?

Tags: cocoa

How do I make a thumbnail view (It's not image) form a custom view(NSView)?

If the custom NSView's content changed that thumbnail view will be changed.

It's looks like ibook author.

Thanks all.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/114755931805273493604/albums/5753531972174581009

Comment: Thanks so much.
I tried to make an thumbnail image, but weal with image too slow.

Comment: Look at CAReplicatorLayer, it may be helpful to create such a "Mini-Map". (thanks to @Gralex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I suggest you do some more Googling next time, and tell us what you have tried**, but I'll answer anyways:

You may want to use `NSView`'s `-(void)cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:` to create an `NSImage` which contains the thumbnail. The following is what I use in an app of mine:

```
- (NSImage *)snapshotForRect:(NSRect)destinationRect {
    NSView *view = ... // view you want thumbnail of
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:destinationRect];
    [view cacheDisplayInRect:destinationRect toBitmapImageRep:imageRep];
    NSImage *renderedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[imageRep
                                                            size]];
    [renderedImage addRepresentation:imageRep];
    return [renderedImage autorelease];
}
```

Or use the variety of other methods available.

[How do I take a "screenshot" of an NSView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251261/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-of-an-nsview)

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=NSView+NSImage&btnK=)

Comment: Thanks so much.
I tried this way, But I encountered performance issue. If I make an image from custom view. this way too slow.

Comment: Have you profiled to see if the performance backup is in your drawing or in how Cocoa is calling you? How often are you taking the snapshot?