# Placing Strings at a specific point on images in objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, image, macos, drawing

I'm trying to create an image made out of text in objective c, but I can't figure out how to put the text onto a new image. The basic idea is that it's going to be shapes made out of text, so I need to be able to specify points. Currently I am trying to do it with a bitmap, but the format doesn't really matter. I may be missing something simple, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to render your text and other things to a custom UIView.  After that, you can capture that UIView to a UIImage.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display) on SO will help in terms of rendering the UIView to UIImage.  There are various tutorials about rendering a custom UIView.  You may just want to override a particular component as well such as overriding the UITextField.

For OSX, you'd want to look into NSView and NSImage - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251261/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-of-an-nsview) may help.

Comment: I'm trying to make this for OSX. Is there an equivalent of UIView and UIImage that I can use?

Comment: Take a look at NSView and NSImage.